# Import a Mongo Database into a Docker Container

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have a `docker container` generated from a `docker image` which has `mongoDB` installed. I want to export a database from my local machine and import it into that `docker container`.

What're the steps for that?

I tried to export the whole db by `mongodump` and then copy the dump file into the container with  `docker cp`. But feels like that's not the correct way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use something called Docker Volume for that. It is used to store files or anything and it won't wipe out even if container is removed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to copy the file. As long as you can access mongo on a port that's open, just use mongorestore from the comfort of your local machine, e.g.

```
mongodump --uri 'mongodb://localhost:27017/yourdatabase' --archive=<your file> --gzip
mongorestore --uri 'mongodb://remotehost:27017/yourdatabase' --archive=<your file> --gzip
```

Comment: So you mean dumping the db in local and then running restore command from my local machine with docker container uri would import the db to docker container? Can you please explain?

Comment: Exactly that.You just need to get your hostnames and ports right and it will work.

Comment: for someone looking to restore from folder.

mongorestore --uri 'mongodb://localhost:27017/db_name' /Users/deepakpoojari/Downloads/dbdump/