# Is it possible to mount my existing Mongo DataBase with docker-compose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, yaml

After some months of development I got to a point where it is better to dockerize my MERN application. I managed to create **.yaml** file and everything is working OK but the problem is that I already have big amount of data that is collected. I want  to be able to mount this data to container but I don't know how to do it. Read a lot of stuff but still my data is not appearing after composing the applications. Here is how my **docker-compose.yaml** file looks-like:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  #MongoDB Service
  mongo_db:
    container_name: db_container
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 2717:27017
    volumes: 
      - /mnt/c/temp/mongo/db:/data/db 

  #Node API Service
  api:
    build: .
    ports: 
     - 4001:4001
    environment:
      PORT: 4001
      MONGODB_URI: mongodb://db_container:27017
      DB_NAME: project-system
    depends_on:
      - mongo_db
  
volumes:
  mongo_db:
```

As you can see in this row:

```
  volumes: 
      - /mnt/c/temp/mongo/db:/data/db
```

I am trying to point the path from my C:\ drive but this doesn't work. I also tried the same row in:

```
volumes:
  mongo_db:
```

(the bottom of file) but again without success. Basically my existing DB is on

> C:\data\db

How can I point this to be the source of MongoDB service?

Comment: Are you trying to mount the local MongoDB to docker MongoDB?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara yes

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create the dump from local MongoDB and copy those files to docker MongoDB. You can use these commands to create:

```
mongodump --uri 'mongodb://localhost:27017/yourdatabase' --archive=<your file> --gzip
mongorestore --uri 'mongodb://remotehost:27017/yourdatabase' --archive=<your file> --gzip
```

You should be able to access the docker from local host.

Note: Reference this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400292/import-a-mongo-database-into-a-docker-container) if you don't get it correct.

You can do these changes on the path you are mounting to make data persistent. Create a new folder `C:/data/docker_mongo` to make data persistent.

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  #MongoDB Service
  mongo_db:
    container_name: db_container
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 2717:27017
    volumes: 
      - C:/data/docker_mongo:/data/db 

  #Node API Service
  api:
    build: .
    ports: 
     - 4001:4001
    environment:
      PORT: 4001
      MONGODB_URI: mongodb://db_container:27017
      DB_NAME: project-system
    depends_on:
      - mongo_db
  
volumes:
  mongo_db:
```

Comment: mongodump  and mongorestore - should I use it in mongoshell or via cmd?

Comment: from the system, not in the mongo shell. Check [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/) for reference.